# Select multiple values from different rows on table_a into one new row on table_b

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like below:

```
'table_a'
Type | Value
-----+------------
000  | 100020003
001  | 004
002  | 5000600070008
```

I need to end up with a result set that is like below:

```
'table_b' 
 ---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4     ETC...
```

I have used substring to pull 1, 2, and 3 where type = 000.  Now I need to do the same with type 001 and 002 but how can they be joined together to create one row in 'table_b'?

So far I have used the below to populate 1, 2 and 3 but I have no idea how to select the data from the remaining rows.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Value,1,1) AS val_1
       SUBSTRING(Value,5,1) AS val_2
       SUBSTRING(Value,9,1) AS val_3
  FROM table_a
 WHERE type = 000
```

Next query would be like this:
     SELECT SUBSTRING(Value,3,1) AS val_4
       FROM table_a
      WHERE type = 001

So as you can see I cannot use a union because I am not selecting the same number of items in each select statement.

The data I am pulling from is not this uniform but hopefully this conveys what I need to do correctly.  I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Value,1,1) || "val_1",
       SUBSTRING(Value,5,1) || "val_2",
       SUBSTRING(Value,9,1) || "val_3",
  FROM table_a
 WHERE type = 000
```